# Error during build : What is causing Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]: Channel closed?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gatsby

Running `npm run build` on the command line returns the below error.  Attempting to deploy a Gatsby site.  After spending a good amount of time researching the error, I'm not coming up with much info.

Has anyone experienced this type of error?  Any thoughts on how to debug?

```
Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]: Channel closed
    at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:704:16)
    at reportSuccess (/Users/chrisyoung/Documents/master-gatsby-master/working/gatsby/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:83:11)
    at tryCatcher (/Users/chrisyoung/Documents/master-gatsby-master/working/gatsby/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/chrisyoung/Documents/master-gatsby-master/working/gatsby/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/chrisyoung/Documents/master-gatsby-master/working/gatsby/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/chrisyoung/Documents/master-gatsby-master/working/gatsby/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/chrisyoung/Documents/master-gatsby-master/working/gatsby/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
    at Promise._fulfill (/Users/chrisyoung/Documents/master-gatsby-master/working/gatsby/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:673:18)
    at MappingPromiseArray.PromiseArray._resolve (/Users/chrisyoung/Documents/master-gatsby-master/working/gatsby/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:127:19)
    at MappingPromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (/Users/chrisyoung/Documents/master-gatsby-master/working/gatsby/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/map.js:108:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/chrisyoung/Documents/master-gatsby-master/working/gatsby/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:609:26)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/chrisyoung/Documents/master-gatsby-master/working/gatsby/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/chrisyoung/Documents/master-gatsby-master/working/gatsby/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/Users/chrisyoung/Documents/master-gatsby-master/working/gatsby/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (/Users/chrisyoung/Documents/master-gatsby-master/working/gatsby/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/chrisyoung/Documents/master-gatsby-master/working/gatsby/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
    at internal/child_process.js:708:35
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
  code: 'ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved : removed all console.logs from all src files as well as gatsby-*.js